# String subclass workaround in Swift

Tags: swift, string, email, struct, subclass

In my app I work with various structs that should really be basically just String subclasses, but String is a struct itself so it’s not possible to subclass it. For example, I have an Email object with a single `address` variable and then computed variables such as `isValid` or functions such as `compose()`. The point is that it seems ridiculous to access the actual email address through the `address` property when the whole object should, in fact, be the address.

So what is the proper way to create an `Email` object? Is this the only way? Or is there a way around subclassing string so that my email struct is actually a string just with some email-specific functions?

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I have more objects like this. For example, I have an address object representing a physical address (as in location) which has its own isValid variable that differs from the email one. That means that I would have to change it into for example .isValidEmail and .isValidAddress, adding a lot of methods to String which doesn’t seem right. Furthermore, custom structs allow me to constrain the type of a variable to for example an email only, which means I can do all sorts of checking to make sure an email is always an email whereas a string can be any string.

Comment: What's the issue with just creating a struct that wraps a `String` value? Subclassing `String`, if it were possible, would lead to many nonsensical consequences. `String` has a whole bunch of methods that have no business being present on an e-mail type. (sub-stringing, upper/lower casing, being initializable from integers

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping a string value?

Comment: @DenisBalko I wrote up an answer to illustrate what I mean

Comment: @DenisBalko Having a type called, for example, `EmailAddress`, which contains an `isValid` method, doesn't make much sense. If `isValid` is `false`, then you really just have a convoluted `String`, not a true e-mail address. Failable initializers are great for this, so that you know if you ever encounter a `EmailAddress` instance, it's already guaranteed to be valid.

Comment: Then a struct wrapper is basically what I have now, except for the failed initialiser. I only moved from Objective-C to Swift recently so I am still exploring what can be done which is why I ask this, I was hoping I could assign my email object directly to say text field because saying emailAddress.stringValue feels a bit ridiculous since email address is really a string. Anyways, first time I hear of failable initialisers so thank you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
import Foundation

struct EmailAddress {
    let stringValue: String

    static func isValidEmailAddress(_ s: String) -> Bool {
        //implement me
        return true
    }

    init?(fromString s: String) {
        guard EmailAddress.isValidEmailAddress(s) else { return nil }
        self.stringValue = s
    }

    var localPart: String {
        return stringValue.components(separatedBy: "@").first!
    }

    var domain: String {
        return stringValue.components(separatedBy: "@").last!
    }

    // expose other functions that make sense to e-mail addresses.
    // importantly, this doesn't expose *all* String methods,
    // most of which wouldn't make sense in the context of a String
}
```

Comment: But how is this different from "For example, I have an Email object with a single address variable and then computed variables such as isValid or functions such as compose()" and so on? If the OP didn't like that why does he like this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `extension` is something that you also have in mind, but if you feel uncomfortable using the name `String` for your `Email` object... then  I would simply suggest the followings:

```
protocol Email {
    func compose() -> Email
    var isValidEmail: Bool
}

extension String: Email {
    func compose() -> Email {
         return something...
    }
    ...
}

var a: Email = "abc"
a.compose()
```

But of course this won't clear your doubts about `String` having connections to `Email` features.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Alexander's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973119/425694) above, in case you wanted to use this custom type in one of your **Codable** conforming API model:

```
struct SomeModel: APIModel, Codable {
  let id: String
  let emailAddress: EmailAddress?
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case emailAddress = "email_address"
  }
}
```

Your `EmailAddress` type might look something like this:

```
struct EmailAddress: RawRepresentable, Codable {
  typealias RawValue = String
  
  let rawValue: RawValue

  init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
    guard isValidEmail(rawValue) else { return nil }
    self.rawValue = rawValue
  }
  
  var localPart: String {
    rawValue.components(separatedBy: "@").first!
  }

  var domain: String {
    rawValue.components(separatedBy: "@").last!
  }

  // expose other functions that make sense to e-mail addresses.
  // importantly, this doesn't expose *all* String methods,
  // most of which wouldn't make sense in the context of a String
}
```

Which could then have the ff results:

**1. Valid Email Address**

```
let model = try! SomeModel.decode([
  "id": "xyz",
  "email_address": "user@domain.com"
])

print(model.emailAddress)            // Optional(EmailAddress(rawValue: "user@domain.com"))
print(model.emailAddress?.localPart) // Optional("user")
print(model.emailAddress?.domain)    // Optional("domain.com")
```

**2. Invalid Email Address**

(Don't know why the server would give you an invalid email address though. But possible.)

```
let model = try! SomeModel.decode([
  "id": "xyz",
  
  // Fatal error: "Cannot initialize EmailAddress from invalid String value foo.bar"
  "email_address": "foo.bar"
])
```

**3. No value at all**

```
let model = try! SomeModel.decode([
  "id": "xyz"
])
print(model.emailAddress) // nil
```

The benefit of pairing your **Codable** with **RawRepresentable** protocol is that it calls the latter's failable initializer implicitly and throws out `DecodingError.dataCorrupted` if in case it failed.

Answer (score 0):

If your subclass wont have properties but only have helper functions, I suggest using `typealias`.

```
typealias EmailString = String

extension EmailString {
   func isValid() -> Bool { ... }
}
```

And I don't think Email should have a `compose` function.